# Bootstrap 5 Toggle Check Box Value in JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

If I have the following Bootstrap 5 toggle check box, how do I get its value in Javascript?

```
   <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input tt" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchTT" checked />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Travel Trailer</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. (_Do_ tag Bootstrap 5 below the post.)

Comment: Also, this isn't a Bootstrap question. It's just JavaScript.